# custom adm file for IE search providers on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, internet-explorer, group-policy

I have been stumped by this issue for some time, I created a custom ADM template for a customer to populate the search providers in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.
The custom ADM works fine and I have set 3 search providers, the problem is that I cannot change them (the customer wants to change the entry for wikipedia from EN to NL), I edited the ADM file but the clients seem to keep on using the old settings.

Removing/replacing the adm file has no effect either, the settings remain. I used the following article as a base: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918238

For IE8 you need to work with a name instead of a UID for the default entry, that works as expected. but there seems to be no way to change the setting once in place.

Comment: is your adm updating the machine or the user hive?

Answer (score 1):

AD thinks it's the same version as the original and isn't updating its store (one reason ADMX files have version numbers).

I'm sure it's not the best solution, but I've found deleting any GPOs that used the ADM, then deleting the ADM from the central store (assuming you have one setup, in `\\[fqdn]\sysvol\[fqdn]\policies\PolicyDefinitions`) has worked for me.